# authorization: what is the flow for non-first time user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth

I have a site (still on localhsot).

I want to **authorize** the user against Google and get permission to gmail scope.

- I get a requestToken
- Authorize it
- Save **requestToken** from the queryString into a cookie (?)
  (I don't have **accessToken** by now)
- Upgrade it to accessToken

Then what?

I thought to save **requestToken** and **accessToken** in the DB with some user guid (?)

Are they both parmenent and uniqe?

Will it help next time to avoid the Upgrade it `to accessToken`

When the user come back for the second time - how will I retrieve its access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store the access token with the user data, yes. Then you will set the Forms Authorization cookie as normal against their username or id.

When they come back a second time, if they still have the cookie, then they will be signed in as normal.

If their cookie has expired, ask them to log in with their chosen provider (Google) and retrieve the token again. You will then have to search the data to see if any users have that token already, and if they do, log that user in as normal like you do the first time.

If they log in with a different provider, they will get a different token and will effectively be seen as a different user - how you handle this is a separate issue.

Comment: I wanted to avoid authentication and then authorization (2 steps). Is it possible? For the second time I'm confused - I'll have to use OpenId? I thought to use oAuth only

Comment: You're taking about 2 separate things there. It's simple - the second time you need to retrieve the token again and see if you already have a user with that token or not. If it's the same user logging back in, they will get the same token from their provider - whether you use oAuth or OpenId it's the same thing.

Comment: you mean the `requestToken` ? is it const? i want to avoid "upgrade to access token"

Comment: If you authenticate the same user against an external provider multiple times, you should receive the same auth token back every time.

Comment: but i don't authenticate, I authorize first.

Comment: Perhaps your question should be reworded, as I've now lost what it is you're trying to achieve.